# ASP.NET Resize image before saving?

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

Below is my code to upload and image and save it to be later displayed in a GridView,

How can I resize the image to a small one before saving it if it is too large?

```
if (this.fuUpload.HasFile == true)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\images");
            string filename = this.fuUpload.FileName;
            this.fuUpload.SaveAs(path + @"\" + filename);
            this.image.ImageUrl = @"\images\" + filename;
        }
```

Comment: google for ".net resize image". There are plenty of examples, such as this here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703873/how-to-proportional-resize-image-of-any-type-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ImageResizer for ASP.NET:

http://imageresizing.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)  class built in System.Web.Helpers assembly. Take a look at [Working with Images in an ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/9-working-with-images) guide.