# Rotating on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Something I've wanted to learn for quite a time now, but haven't been able to figure out.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mobilpadde/Xt7ag/

Then you move the mouse, it follows, which is the easy part, but I want to rotate too, like always look in the direction of the mouse, but not so static, more like, if you move your mouse up, it should kinda rotate first, and then you move the mouse further away, it should begin to follow again (If you know what I mean).

Is that something simple to do, or 3k lines? (Or maybe a jQuery plugin?)

Comment: Rotation can only be achieved via CSS or the canvas element. JavaScript alone can't do it.

Comment: @j08691 I know, it's just how you do it...

Comment: If you know then you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Through it was kind of implicit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiya I got it something more closer by using an old post of mine : **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Z3pGQ/3/

I am still working, will flick you more smoother version *or* if you can improve before me:

Old post: [Rotating an element based on cursor position in a separate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972449/rotating-an-element-based-on-cursor-position-in-a-separate-element)

Hope it helps,  I am trying to make it smoother now, cheers

**Sample code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $(".firefly").css({
            "top": (e.pageY * 2) + "px",
            "left": (e.pageX * 2 + 130) + "px"
        });
    })
})
var img = $(".firefly");
if (img.length > 0) {
    var offset = img.offset();

    function mouse(evt) {
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
        var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}​
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Uhhh, thats might be helpfull :D

Comment: @Moiblpadde :) Cooleos, its evening at my side of world I will flick yo a smoother version if I am done, (**Please note**: `you should play around with the degrees variable and the x and y axis calc`) I shared it with you just in case you can play around and come with any version `:)` good luck I will be back in a tick, have a nice one,

Comment: Was early morning from my side of the world, then I was asking this. But I kind of came to some point that I like (But not completely) http://jsfiddle.net/Mobilpadde/Yf5Eg/

Answer (score 0):

This is going to involve a lot more math than I want to do right now, but you can apply rotations with css easily. Here are the properties for mozilla and webkit, you can see the rest of the (IE,Opera...) [at this page](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate). Here is your function with a 120deg rotation applied. You will still need to calculate the proper rotation, and adjust the `left` and `top` accordingly.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
                $(".firefly").css({
                    "top":(e.pageY*2)+"px",
                    "left":(e.pageX*2+130)+"px",
                    "-moz-transform": "rotate(120deg)",
                    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(120deg)"});
            })
```

Comment: What I've imagined too (calculate by using top and left), but was hoping for something easier... D:

Comment: I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for that http://pixelscommander.com/en/iphone-development/rotate-html-elements-with-mouse/