# jquery mousemove how to stop

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/193/ where I want my object to move only when the red square is pressed, but I cannot remove the mousemove action when the user releases the mouse. It still moves after that.

HTML:

```
<div class="pointer">
    <div class="marker"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marker {
    background:#ED1C24;
    height:2px;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    width:7px
}
.pointer {
    height:72px;
    position:absolute;
    top:82px;
    width:72px;
    border:1px solid red;
 left:100px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var img = $('.pointer');

var offset = img.offset();

function mouse(evt) {
    var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
    var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
    img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}

img.mousedown(function (e) {
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}).mouseup(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

The original rotation script was provided by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235298/1168944

Comment: This is a _little_ better, if you're still hovering over the box when mouseup, it will stop: http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/195/

Comment: if you are using older version of jQuery then use `bind` and `unbind`. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/204/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your script...

```
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(document).off("mousemove", mouse);
});
```

It unbinds the `mousemove` event handler whenever you release the mouse button.

http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/201/

I updated it to a later version of jQuery as well, in order to accommodate `off()`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a bool to check if mouseDown is true/false

```
 var mouseDown = false;
 if(mouseDown ==true){
   //move code
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/194/)