# How to position one element relative to another at a specific point when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried several other codes mentioned here on stackoverflow, all work in specific positions and specific distances. I tried to use the MAP> AREA tag, but the plugins found can not keep resizing, leaving the point completely out of the picture.

Need to position an element over an image in a specific point. 
Other words, the image will reduce when I resize the browser and the point must be kept exactly where he is.

Look at the example of three images: 
1 - [Image FULL](http://www.loverde.com.br/temp_files/bigger.png) and point in the correct place; 
2 - [Medium image](http://www.loverde.com.br/temp_files/medium.png). Here has begun to lose; 
3 - [Not much smaller image](http://www.loverde.com.br/temp_files/semi_small.png). Here now very out;

I am currently using this code:

```
$('.btParede').css("top", ( $('.imageBox').offset().top + 200 ) + "px"); 
$('.btParede').css("left", ( $('.imageBox').offset().left + $('.imageBox').width() - 400 ) + "px");
```

There is a more specific position relative to another element when it is resized without losing the specific point?

Thanks

**** I forgot to mentioned this ****
I use "fitToParent" [jQuery resize to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682495/jquery-resize-to-aspect-ratio#1682739) to scale and reload and maintain aspect ratio of the image inside the document

Here is another example http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/ypb5P/1/ that works fine when resize, but when reload, mess it up.. Anyone experienced this? Works one way and not another?

Thanks again!

Comment: First of all why dont you just do this in your CSS? Second you should be using percentages there is no way to make this work with pixels and have a re-sizing image unless you can figure out the exact ratios for the X and Y of where you overlay image should be. Try playing around with top: x% and left: x%

Comment: Sorry i shouldn't say impossible. You could do it with media queries and set you overlay image exactly where you want it for multiple different background sizes. This may not be a good solution though as then you would have to have specific breakpoints where the BG image changes size instead of just re sizing fluidly.

Comment: tried using CSS and also with percentage still falls outside the specific point and when smaller, the worse it gets. If reloading the page, it gets worse

Comment: It will definitely take a lot of trial and error if you can recreate in a fiddle or codepen I will try and take a look.

Comment: See this almost perfect example http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/ypb5P/1/ work nice when resize, but when reload... mess it up.. i forget to mentioned that i use "fitToParent" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682495/jquery-resize-to-aspect-ratio#1682739 to scale and reload and maintain aspect ratio of the image inside the document

Comment: hmmm it works fine for me in Chrome. Even when i re-size and then reload the page.

Comment: You have add the fitToParent on this jsfiddle ?

Comment: No i just opened the fiddle you posted in your last comment.

Comment: That was what I meant above your "chrome" comment, in MY code